# Efficient implementation of a threaded console window

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, console, thread-safety

I have a Win32 application that consists of two components: A main window that acts as the app's interface and a secondary modeless dialog that functions as a console. The application generates copious amounts of debug text during certain (regular) operations.

Having to update the console's edit control during every debug print call is rather expensive given my constraints. My intention is to create a critical section synchronized message queue that is dumped periodically by a worker thread. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how such an implementation can be coded.

Comment: What does *CS-synchronized* mean?

Comment: Critical Section - synchronized. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: This question is too vague, try to be more specific. What particular part is unclear to you?

Comment: Well, no part in particular. My current setup, which is what I've described above as my intention, seems to create a deadlock when sending messages to the edit control. So I was hoping to hear from other developers about how this can be achieved safely.

Comment: How are you sending messages to the edit control?

Comment: The application's setup isn't as straight forward as I've alluded to - I'm actually injecting my code into the said executable (which has its message pump, as expected). I use CreateDialogParam to create the console from a dialog template and use the standard Edit_* macros to send messages to its controls.

Comment: @shadeMe It's possible, just possible, that there is a problem caused by injecting your code into another executable and piggy-backing on its message pump

Comment: Yeah, there is always that. At any rate, Kyle Alon's post reminded me that I could use a timer to do the job in the main thread itself. I guess I'll be sticking to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using a timer in the main thread and it worked well enough for me. My thanks to the posters!

Answer (score 1):

In the worker thread, lock the CS and add to a shared data structure.  In the GUI thread, set a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and in the WM_TIMER message handler, lock the CS, remove from the shared data structure, and append to the edit control.

Comment: Your post prompted me to give timers a try, and it worked! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try sleeping the message pump on the edit control window, instead of running a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just take care of this recurrent problem relating to multithreading and GUI:

Never access to Gui elements from another thread, you have to post message to the window , so the code will be executed in the main thread when changing something in the GUI.